# Android WorkManager observe progress

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager for deferred work in my app.
The total work is divided into a number of chained workers, and I'm having trouble showing the workers' progress to the user (using progress bar).

I tried creating one tag and add it to the different workers, and inside the workers update the progress by that tag, but when I debug I always get progress is '0'.

Another thing I noticed is that the workManager's list of work infos is getting bigger each time I start the work (even if the workers finished their work).

Here is my code:

```
//inside view model
    private val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(appContext)
    internal val progressWorkInfoItems: LiveData<List<WorkInfo>>


    init
    {
        progressWorkInfoItems = workManager.getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS)
    }

    companion object
    {
        const val TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS = "saving_progress_tag"
    }

      //inside a method
        var workContinuation = workManager.beginWith(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(firstWorker::class.java))

        val secondWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SecondWorker>()
        secondWorkRequest.addTag(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS)
        secondWorkRequest.setInputData(createData())
        workContinuation = workContinuation.then(secondWorkRequest.build())

        val thirdWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ThirdWorker>()
        thirdWorkRequest.addTag(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS)
        thirdWorkRequest.setInputData(createData())
        workContinuation = workContinuation.then(thirdWorkRequest.build())

        workContinuation.enqueue()

//inside the Activity

viewModel.progressWorkInfoItems.observe(this, observeProgress())

    private fun observeProgress(): Observer<List<WorkInfo>>
    {
        return Observer { listOfWorkInfo ->
            if (listOfWorkInfo.isNullOrEmpty()) { return@Observer }

            listOfWorkInfo.forEach { workInfo ->
                if (WorkInfo.State.RUNNING == workInfo.state)
                {
                    val progress = workInfo.progress.getFloat(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS, 0f)
                    progress_bar?.progress = progress
                }
            }
        }
    }

//inside the worker

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        setProgress(workDataOf(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS to 10f))
        ...
        ...
        Result.success()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my analysis I have found that there might be two reasons why you always get `0`

- `setProgress` is set just before the `Result.success()` in the `doWork()` of the worker then it's lost and you never get that value in your listener. This could be because the state of the worker is now `SUCCEEDED`
- the worker is completing its work in fraction of seconds

Lets take a look at the following code

```
class Worker1(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context,workerParameters) {

override fun doWork(): Result {

    setProgressAsync(Data.Builder().putInt("progress",10).build())
    for (i in 1..5) {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000)
    }
    setProgressAsync(Data.Builder().putInt("progress",50).build())
    SystemClock.sleep(1000)
    return Result.success()
  }
}
```

In the above code

- if you remove only the first sleep method then the listener only get the progres`50`
- if you remove only the second sleep method then the listener only get the progress `10`
- If you remove both then the you get the default value `0`

This analysis is based on the **WorkManager version 2.4.0**

Hence I found that the following way is better and always reliable to show the progress of various workers of your chain work.

I have two workers that needs to be run one after the other. If the first work is completed then 50% of the work is done and 100% would be done when the second work is completed.

Two workers

```
class Worker1(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context,workerParameters) {

override fun doWork(): Result {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        Log.e("worker", "worker1----$i")
    }
    return Result.success(Data.Builder().putInt("progress",50).build())
  }
}

class Worker2(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context,workerParameters) {

override fun doWork(): Result {
    for (i in 5..10) {
       Log.e("worker", "worker1----$i")
    }
    return Result.success(Data.Builder().putInt("progress",100).build())
  }
}
```

Inside the activity

```
    workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)

    workRequest1 = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Worker1::class.java)
            .addTag(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS)
            .build()

    workRequest2 = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(Worker2::class.java)
            .addTag(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS)
            .build()


   findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->

        workManager?.
        beginUniqueWork(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS,ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,workRequest1)
                ?.then(workRequest2)
                ?.enqueue()
    })

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

     workManager?.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest1.id)
            ?.observe(this, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
                if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    val progress = workInfo.outputData
                    val value = progress.getInt("progress", 0)
                    progressBar?.progress =  value
                }
            })

    workManager?.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest2.id)
            ?.observe(this, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
                if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    val progress = workInfo.outputData
                    val value = progress.getInt("progress", 0)
                    progressBar?.progress =  value
                }
            })
```

The reason workManager's list of work infos is getting bigger each time the work is started even if the workers finished their work is because of
`workManager.beginWith(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(firstWorker::class.java))`

instead one need to use

`workManager?.beginUniqueWork(TAG_SAVING_PROGRESS, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,OneTimeWorkRequest.from(firstWorker::class.java))`

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#unique)

Answer (score 0):

The `setProgress` method is to observe intermediate progress in a single Worker (as explained in the [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress)):

> Progress information can only be observed and updated while the ListenableWorker is running.

For this reason, the progress information is available only till a Worker is active (e.g. it is not in a terminal state like `SUCCEEDED`, `FAILED` and `CANCELLED`). [This WorkManager guide covers Worker's states](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation).

My suggestion is to use the Worker's unique ID to identify which worker in your chain is not yet in a terminal state. You can use `WorkRequest`'s [`getId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest#getId()) method to retrieve its unique ID.